# Elastic search un-searchable feild?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, mapping, sharding

I have an index with a mapping field of type text, its called ean_code, but when I try to retrieve documents querying this field, it says 0 results.

I am running the command:

```
GET <index-name>/_doc/1877
```

This gives me back: [image]

I can clearly see the ean_code is there, but when I try running this query:

```
POST <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product_sale_elements.ean_code": {
        "query": "9004464248405"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It says 0 hits. What am I missing? Why can't this field be searched upon?

Here is the mapping:
[image]

Comment: Is `product_sale_elements` of type `nested` by any chance?

Comment: Hello, yes. It is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `product_sale_elements` is of type `nested` you need to use a `nested` query, like this:

```
POST <index-name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "product_sale_elements",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "product_sale_elements.ean_code": {
            "query": "9004464248405"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```